# Exporting to .mov from premiere cc? queuing as .mxf?

Tags: premiere

I am trying to export an .mov video from premiere??? So i am doing this by going: File > Export > Media...

Ok so I got Quicktime predefined in the dropdown then I select H264 from the drop down menu and viola all the settings that I need are here ready to go. See image below...

[image]

As you can see my output name is **duffy_fuck.mov**

But when you queue it to Adobe Media Encode it outputs an .mxf file..

[image]

I'm not even kidding, as an avid abobe user all I am doing it selecting quicktime as a format and encoding h264 I promise. I've tried outputting other files and they all pass through as the premiere output name..

Seriously WTF!

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Usually you export directly to AME and set your format there, so the workflow you use is not very common and it might have gone undetected in bug testing. I would report it to Adobe. https://www.adobe.com/cfusion/mmform/index.cfm?name=wishform&loc=en

Comment: Yeah it is odd, not had an issue like this other systems, must be my install that is messed up because anyway I try though media encoder, .mov can't be done. It comes out as .mxf files every time. I just used an alternative encoder. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Maybe you dont have QuickTime installed? Could explain why it chooses a different format as a sort of fallback.